# Python pandas remove first minute for every day from a pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, grouping

I've got the contract_df data frame structured as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quote_ts': ['2020-05-15 14:01:00.522517', 
                                '2020-05-15 14:01:00.599999', 
                                '2020-05-15 15:00:01.234517',
                                '2020-05-16 14:00:00.312518',
                                '2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517',
                                '2020-05-17 14:00:00.122983',
                                '2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567',
                                '2020-05-18 14:00:00.522517'],
                   'price': [1000, 1200, 1300, 1000, 1400, 1800, 1900, 1600]})

df = df.set_index('quote_ts')
```

I need to remove the first minute for each day so that the resulting data frame would be equal to :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quote_ts': ['2020-05-15 15:00:01.234517',
                                '2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517',
                                '2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567'],
                   'price': [1300, 1400, 1600]})

df = df.set_index('quote_ts')
```

The first minute is not always the same across the different days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `isin` with `groupby` `head`

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
toremove = df.groupby(df.index.date).head(1).index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df = df[~df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').isin(toremove)]
df
                            price
quote_ts                         
2020-05-15 15:00:01.234517   1300
2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517   1400
2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567   1900
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby.rank` to create a boolean mask

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
m = ((s.floor('Min').to_series().groupby(s.date).rank(method='dense') > 1)
                                                .to_numpy())
df_final = df[m]

Out[338]:
                            price
quote_ts
2020-05-15 15:00:01.234517   1300
2020-05-16 14:01:00.582517   1400
2020-05-17 14:02:00.524567   1900
```